# I wanna disable the Exit quick edit (not quick edit) in sharepoint online

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-online

I have a list with columns on sharepoint online that I add programmatically but every time i enter the Log List page there is a button (only 1) that says "Exit quick edit" that I have to click in order to get to the edit view, new, export to excel etcetc.

I have read 100 blogs about removing the quick edit but not to remove the button before that.

So how can i remove that first button?

Programmatically or manually on sharepoint online would be nice to know how.

Thanks alot.

Comment: So you want to remove the Exit button of quick edit but keep the quick edit function?  Because once you see the button means you are already in the quick edit form. You can still edit your column if you disable the quick edit function.  Just not the quick edit on the fly.

Comment: I figured it out but I still dont know how to change the view to standard view programmatically. @NaaHCat

Comment: Do you mean change it to default view of your column/library?